# I have a problem on recycler view animation

Tags: android

I have a problem with recycler View

I build a social media app

and in my app one feature is photo sharing can I transaction photo with animation in recycler view

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Your question is very generic though, thus, most of the people won't be able to help you without knowing more details. Head over to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for a short intro on how to ask a good question.

Comment: Yes you can animate image view in recyclerview